# Calculation of NADPH molecules number needed to reduce a substrate in enzymatic reaction

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes, biosynthesis

I am inquiring if it is just simply possible - as it seems to be - to calculate the number of NADPH molecules needed by an enzyme (let say for example Dihydrofolate Reductase DHFR) to reduce the substrate (FH2 or BH2 for DHFR) to (FH4 or BH4) directly from the apparent enzyme reaction?

**In DHFR case, can I simply figure it out that I need two NADPH molecules to reduce (FH2) to (FH4)?**

Here is the reaction of reducing FH2 to FH4:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/DHFRmechanism.png

Or is there anything else to keep in mind?

In the figure in the link, the NADPH transferd Hydride, but where did the positive hydrogen come from?

Comment: But then where does the other hydrogen come from? one of them comes from NADP(H), which is in hydride form, but what about the second one? it comes in proton form (H+), but from where?